# Minimal footprint Windows instance on OS X to run ActiveX

Tags: windows, macos, virtualization, parallels, nlite

I need to run Windows to be able to use a feature for some remote work. However, I would rather not have a full-blown 20GB (or much more) Windows 8 install for Parallels.

Is there a way to get a barebones Windows virtual environment on a Mac? Something like Windows XP with nLite done for a Mac install? (Using Parallels or something else.)

I cannot run nLite on OS X to begin with. Are there prepared ISO files or something?

Comment: There might be in the future, nlite hasn't been updated in 4 years, so thats unlikely going to ever be updated.  I know there are tools out there already that does this.

Comment: Please don't cross-post in the future. Your question can always be migrated!

Comment: @slhck, Sorry and thanks. How does the migration work?

Comment: If enough users with >3k reputation or one moderator decide that your question is off topic on one site, but on-topic on another, it'll be moved automatically. This means you don't need to post on two sites at the same time – in the best case your question will be migrated to its destination without further ado.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to run ActiveX and do some minimal browser testing try WINE (winehq.org). It allows you to run *some* Windows apps 'natively' without running a virtual machine. In particular you can run IE6.

WINE emulates a Win2k / XP environment though so very new programs and programs created by Microsoft will not usually work well.

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with Windows PE, perhaps?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824964.aspx#WindowsPELimitations

Answer (score 0):

There is a script for OSX which helps you install IE App Compat VHDs as Virtualbox VMs, which are primarily used to test Web site layouts on IE browsers, but could be used for ActiveX too. You can find the script on [Github](https://github.com/xdissent/ievms), and more info on IE App Compat VMs from [Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575).

The platforms provided are: IE6 on XP, IE7 on Vista, IE8+9 on Win7. If IE6 is enough, it has the smallest footprint. If not, I'd recommend skipping the Vista version and going for Win7.