# Enable ActiveX on MacOS?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, mac, microsoft-office, activex

I've developed a custom tool around Excel and I've just learned that it should work on MacOS too...

The **only** problem I've got is that the whole tool work around ActiveX comboboxes, which are not supported but MacOS... (T_T)

I could break the whole tool and almost restart it from scratch to break every combobox into supported components, but I've seen around a few pages talking about enabling ActiveX on MacOS.

But they talked about an installer that was no more available via provided link...

**Any one know any way I could try to enable ActiveX on MacOS ?**
Or is absolutely sure that it isn't possible, so that I just get on with rebuilding... :/

Comment: Why are you even using AcitveX on Windows any more? It doesn't work in Edge. It's never worked on Mac.

Comment: ActiveX is dead, period. If you must work on your combo boxes on a Mac, you can do it via form control (to enter data), and if you must edit the box properties (change or rename items, etc...), you must use userform. Both are available in the Developer Tools in the Ribbon. See here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-for-mac-2016-customize-combo-box/6f79b9d1-199d-4e4b-b267-1b737b654c36

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimal footprint Windows instance on OS X to run ActiveX](https://superuser.com/questions/505126/minimal-footprint-windows-instance-on-os-x-to-run-activex)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Mac compatible ActiveX capability.  ActiveX is a Windows-only technology. Microsoft is dropping ActiveX for better security. Active-X was never ported to the Mac. Since it doesn't exist on the Mac, and no one (not Apple, Microsoft or anyone else) has invested in Active-X to make it cross-platform, you must use either standard legacy controls, or invest what it takes to port Active-X to the Mac.